# Unstyle Orchard Projection Query Grouping Property

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

Whenever I attempt to utilize the Grouping Property for my projection/query layout, standard bullet points appear at the top of my project.

This is regardless of the "list-unstyle" markup I add to the specific property, HTML properties, and everything else. The rendered HTML looks like so:

```
<ul>
<li class="first">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <!-- ... content ... -->
</ul>
</li>
<li class="last">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <!-- ... content ... -->
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Which renders:

[image: Where are these bullet points coming from?]

I'm able to unstyle each projection item/custom content type but for the life of me I cannot determine where to add a "list-unstyle" class to the `<ul>` that is acting as the grouping property.

The Shape Tracing Module just lists them as `<Place Parts_ProjectionPart_List="Content:5"/>` but suppressing that removes all the projection items, not just the top bullet points.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Create an alternate for that template. http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove bullet points through via CSS using:

> ul { list-style:none; }

This will remove the bullet point for all unordered lists, including nested lists. To target a more specific area (eg. the projection output on a projection page) you could use:

```
.projection-page ul { list-style:none; }
```

If you are using a projection widget, and say you named it 'pictures', then you could use:

```
.widget-pictures ul { list-style:none; }
```